# How to retrieve containers from the deployment in kubernetes from node.js library?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I am working on Kubernetes stuff in `node.js` and I come into the situation that at some logic I have to add a new container in an existing deployment. As far as I know, it is similar to deleting an existing deployment and creating a new deployment adding all the new and old containers. I am using `@kubernetes/client-node` package. My problem is before deleting the old deployment, how can I retrieve all the existing containers from the deployment so that I can add them to the new deployment along with the new containers. Does the `node.js` library provide the option? or do I have to store the existing container config of the deployment somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `node.js` library doesn't provide the option, so I have to store the existing container config of the deployment somewhere else.